# iphone simulator not showing in xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have been using xcode 4.2 for last 3 months. For last two days it is not showing iPhone simulator .But when we change the device option in iOS simulator to retina display it is showing the simulator .i didn't change any settings of xcode.

Answer (score 0):

As I experienced, in Xcode in the circumtances when the target of the Simulator is iPad but your sample code is in iPhone or the sample code(project) you are trying to compile has been compiled in an old version of iOS (or Xcode) the Simulator doesn't give response. But it still compiles the project and saves it to the main page of iPhone(iPad) simulator.. What you need to do is just compile an iOS 5 project and from main page see your app in Simulator